# Flink Nested Json Serialization Issue

Tags: json, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm trying to serialize flink `Row` to kafka, I don't have json schema with me, but have columns names, also `Row` can be accessed with index and fields, with plain json below code is working fine, however with nested json, for type `Row`, it is printing rowking and arity. I'm using `JsonRowSerializationSchema` with `withTypeInfo` builder.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.RowTypeInfo;
import org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.sink.KafkaRecordSerializationSchema;
import org.apache.flink.formats.json.JsonRowSerializationSchema;
import org.apache.flink.types.Row;

public class JsonSerializerBuilder {
  private final String[] columnNames;
 
  public JsonSerializerBuilder(String[] columnNames) {
    this.columnNames = columnNames;
  }

  public KafkaRecordSerializationSchema<Row> build() {

    String outputTopic = "test_topic";

    TypeInformation<Row> opTypeInfo = getTypeInformation();

    JsonRowSerializationSchema jsonRowSerializationSchema =
        JsonRowSerializationSchema.builder().withTypeInfo(opTypeInfo).build();

    return KafkaRecordSerializationSchema.builder()
        .setValueSerializationSchema(jsonRowSerializationSchema)
        .setTopic(outputTopic)
        .build();
  }

  private TypeInformation<Row> getTypeInformation() {
    TypeInformation[] typeInformationArray = new TypeInformation[columnNames.length];
    Arrays.fill(typeInformationArray, TypeInformation.of(Object.class));
    return new RowTypeInfo(typeInformationArray, columnNames);
  }
}
```

```
 input: {"id": 1,"name":"mike","school_details":{"location": "uk","name": "test"}}
 output: {"id": 1,"name":"mike","school_details":{"kind":"INSERT","arity":2}}
```

so basically `Object` `TypeInformation` is not working with `Row` type objects, how can I fix it.

Comment: Hi, is there any reason why you're implementing this serialization code manually rather than using flink-json like described here? https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/table/formats/json/#how-to-create-a-table-with-json-format

JsonRowSerializationSchema is intended for a totally different use case, and we're planning to remove it in near future (see https://lists.apache.org/thread/kstovnbx18sm96x01nf3m1t9l3jhrnys)

Comment: Yes,reason: to use flink-json, we should have destination table schema beforehand. But I want to make it generic without specifying destination schema

Comment: Then I suggest you to deeply convert the Row to your own POJOs, or alternatively to java.util.Map, and then use Jackson ObjectMapper to convert to JSON.
JsonRowSerializationSchema works if you know the complete schema, just using TypeInformation(Object.class) won't work because it won't reflect on the object to know the concrete type (like Jackson does).
I still don't get why flink-json is not suitable for you, as it infers the schema directly from the sql statement, you don't have to define it manually.

Comment: Also, if you have some kind of "external source" where you get the data schema from (e.g. some schema registry), you can implement a custom format as described here: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/sourcessinks/#encoding--decoding-formats This will give you the schema inferred by the planner of the output, and then you can do whatever you want with it before starting writing records.

Comment: I still don't get why flink-json is not suitable for you, as it infers the schema directly from the sql statement, you don't have to define it manually. -> I don't have a SQL, I have a datastream of Row which is some post processed after SQL query

Comment: Then you should map the Row to your POJO and then write the POJO to JSON. This way, you have full control over your model and how you serialize it.

Comment: ya, completely agree, can you check my last comment on your PR: https://github.com/apache/flink-shaded/pull/108, am I on the right path now?